# factorial using recursion+pointers

Tags: c, pointers, factorial

i am learning C programming, i was trying to write a recursive function by using this prototype:

```
void fact(int *n);
```

The parameter of this function should be passed by reference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: so, what have you've done so far? This isn't give-me-anything-I-want site.

Comment: Do you mean to have a return type of `void`?

Comment: Ok. But what's the question?

Answer (score 5):

I don't feel to be helpful in giving a complete solution -- this is just to show there is an answer:

```
void fact(int *n)
{
    if (*n > 1)
    {
        int tmp = *n - 1;
        fact(&tmp);
        *n *= tmp;
    }
}
```

I would never write a factorial function this way.

Comment: Damn, now I feel stupid.